# swift 3: Watch app: if watch goes to sleep there's a delay between interface controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, watch, watchos-2

I have a countdown timer interface controller that will, once the timer gets down to 00:00, launch another interface controller.  If I keep the watch active until the timer reaches 00:00, then the second interface controller launches as it should.  However, if the watch goes to sleep, even if it's active right before the timer reaches 00:00, there will be a delay of several seconds to over a minute before the second interface controller launches.

This defect doesn't appear when running in the watch simulator, just when I'm running on the actual device.

I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3.

Here's my code from the first interface controller:

```
// this func will update the countdown timer
@objc private func updateTimer() {
    totalNumberOfSeconds += 1
    numberOfSeconds += 1
    if (numberOfSeconds == numSecondsInMinute) {
        numberOfSeconds = 0
    }

    // only attempt to open the RacingTimer interface if this IC is visible
    if (isStillVisible) {
        // change to the Racing Timer if the countdown timer hits 00:00
        if (totalNumberOfSeconds > originalSecondsTimeInterval) {
            // the watch must have gone to sleep when the countdown timer
            // hit 00:00, so the total num secs is past the orig timer
            // set the numberOfSeconds to total - original to pass to RacingTimer
            numberOfSeconds = totalNumberOfSeconds - originalSecondsTimeInterval

            // launch the racing timer
            WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["RacingTimer"], contexts: [numberOfSeconds])

            // destroy the timer and reset the vars
            countdownClock.invalidate()
            numberOfSeconds = 0
            totalNumberOfSeconds = 0
        } else if (totalNumberOfSeconds == originalSecondsTimeInterval) {
            // launch the racing timer
            WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["RacingTimer"], contexts: nil)

            // destroy the timer and reset the vars
            countdownClock.invalidate()
            numberOfSeconds = 0
            totalNumberOfSeconds = 0
        }
    }
}


override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    // get race and timer data
    let numSecs = raceDS.timer * 60
    originalSecondsTimeInterval = numSecs
    cdt = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(numSecs))
    countdownTimer.setDate(cdt as Date)
    countdownClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    countdownTimer.start()
}


override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    nearestMinuteButtonOutlet.setTitle("will activate") // debug only
    didAppear()
}


// set the visible boolean to true
override func didAppear() {
    super.didAppear()
    isStillVisible = true
    nearestMinuteButtonOutlet.setTitle("did appear")  // debug only
}


// set the boolean to false
override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
    isStillVisible = false
    nearestMinuteButtonOutlet.setTitle("sleeping")  // debug only
}
```

I'm really at a loss as to why there's a delay if the watch goes to sleep.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  TIA.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out the issue.  It isn't that the second interface controller is delayed in launching, it's that when the watch goes to sleep, the Timer variable (countdownClock) doesn't continue processing in the background.  It stops.  When this happens, the updateTimer() function doesn't get called, therefore the totalNumberOfSeconds variable doesn't get incremented, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the countdownClock running in the background when the watch goes to sleep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `watchOS3` there is no solution to have a `Timer` running in the background. `Timer` objects shouldn't be used for precise time measurements on `iOS` either. On `iOS` you have the alternative to use a `CADisplayLink` for accurate timings, however, this isn't available on `watchOS3/4`.

For measuring time in the background, you should save the current date before the app is going to background and calculate the elapsed time when the app is launched again.

If you simply need the other `InterfaceController` to be visible by the time the user opens your app, you can use the the method described using dates and you can navigate to your other `InterfaceController` as soon as the user opens your app again.

If you need some code to execute when the countdown is finished, you should rather schedule a background task, they are the only methods of running code in the background on `watchOS` at the moment.

Comment: Thanks David.  I found similar issues and suggested work arounds on other boards, so that's the direction I'll take.  I'll just save the date/time stamp in the didDeactivate() and compute how much time passed once the willAppear() fires up and add the elapsed time to my total seconds counter.  A bit ugly, but if that's what's needed, then that's what I'll need to do.